# Python: High Low game v2

Tags: python

Ok, i have mostly created it but there are still some problem.

[Update] I have updated it according to the info, and i got a few more problem.

```
import random

print '|'*20
print '='*20
print 'Instruction'
print 'Enter high, low or quit!'
print 'Press enter without any input too see instruction'
print '='*20
print "="*5+'GAME START'+"="*5
print '='*20
print ''
card = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

choice = ' '
i=0
first = 1
while choice != 'quit':


    card1, card2 = random.sample(card, 2)


    showCard = [card1, card2]
    startCard = card1

    if choice == 'high':
        if card1 > card2:
            print ''
            print str(card1) + ' first card1'
            print str(card2) + ' first card2'
            print ''
            print 'wrong'
            print ''
            print 'Dealer Second card: '+str(card2)
            print '-'*20
            i=i+1
        elif card1 <= card2:
            print ''
            print str(card1) + ' second card1'
            print str(card2) + ' second card2'
            print ''
            print 'correct'
            print ''
            print 'Dealer Second card: '+str(card2)
            print '-'*20
            i=i+1
        else:
            print 'Dealer First card: '+str(card1)
    elif choice == 'low':
        if card1 > card2:
            print 'wrong - testing 3'
            print 'Next card: '+str(card2)
            print '-'*20
        else:
            print 'correct - testing 4'
            print 'Next card: '+str(card2)
            print '-'*20
    elif choice != 'high' or 'low' or 'info':
        print 'Enter high or low only'


    print 'First card 2: '+str(startCard)

    choice = raw_input("Enter: ")

print i
print 'END'
```

Output:

```
====================
=====GAME START=====
====================

Enter high or low only
First card 2: 7
Enter: high

7 second card1
10 second card2

correct

Dealer Second card: 10
---------------------
First card2: 3
Enter: high

6 first card1
5 first card2

wrong

Dealer Second card: 5
```

Problem: At the second loop, how can i set the '6 first card1' before 'Enter: high' user input? (replace "First card2: 3" to "6 first card1")

**PS: use the high input first as low input is still under construction**

thanks

Comment: Couldnt you just move the first two lines of the loop outside?  Besides you shouldnt have your card list declaration inside the loop anyway because it will be re-declared each time you loop anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i have moved the list outside of the loops :)

Answer (score 1):

You could either (if possible) move the declaration outside as taronish4 said or could alter your code so that it looks like this:

```
choice = raw_input("Press enter to start ")
i=-1
first=1
while choice != 'quit':

    card = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    card1, card2 = random.sample(card, 2)

    if first == 1:
        print 'Dealer First card: '+str(card1)
        first = 0

    showCard = [card1, card2]

    if choice == 'high':
```

rest of the code as before.

**EDIT: Solution to additional Problem**

You have to copy this:

```
card1, card2 = random.sample(card, 2)
```

and put it before the loop like this:

```
card = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
card1, card2 = random.sample(card, 2)
choice = ' '
i=0
while choice != 'quit':
```

and then move the call of random.sample inside the loop so that is executed at the end, right before the output like this:

```
print 'First card 2: '+str(startCard)
card1, card2 = random.sample(card, 2)
choice = raw_input("Enter: ")
```

and I would recommend to remove the first=1 declaration since you are not using the variable.

**EDIT: JQKA Problem**

To do this, i would implement a dictionary that returns a string for the numbers 10,11,12,13.
Put this before your code (but after the import statement!)

```
cardDict = {
    2: '2',
    3: '3',
    4: '4',
    5: '5',
    6: '6',
    7: '7',
    8: '8',
    9: '9',
    10: '10',
    11: 'J',
    12: 'Q',
    13: 'K',
    14: 'A'
}
```

then comes the rest of your code.
Don't forget to alter your card list so it looks like this:

```
card=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
```

and everywhere you have something like

```
print card
```

replace it by

```
print cardDict[card]
```

Comment: Thanks, your code can only print 1 "Dealer first card" at the beginning. But i have solved the multiple printing problem

Another problem is the bigger and smaller then.
i have updated it above

Comment: Some questions:
What Python version do you use?
Does the code in your question compile on your system?

Comment: Version: 4.1.13-1 (rev 28904). My code compile to my system.

I have add the output above.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
It have the same problem, but i'v solved it. You just need to put

the "card1, card2 = random.sample(card, 2)" 
before 
"print 'First card 2: '+str(startCard)"

Comment: Oh, and 1 last question. if i want to add J,Q,K,A inside, how do i set it to know which is big and which is small?

Comment: I would just use 11, 12, 13, 14 instead and care about converting to JQKA in the output (maybe write a function for this).

Dirty method: `if card2 == 11: print "J"` and so on

Comment: do i put this inside or outside of the loop?

Comment: added it to the solution

Comment: @user2693620: Fixed a minor coding error above (note the = after cardDict)

Comment: @user2693620: would be kind if you marked the answer as correct if it worked for you. thanks